# How to keep track of the id that is being passed to other web page?

Tags: jquery

I am fairly new to html and js.
Let say if I have the following codes in index.html:

```
<a href='edit.html?id=1>item1</a>
<a href='edit.html?id=2>item2</a>
<a href='edit.html?id=3>item3</a>
```

then I create a page named edit.html
But How do I keep track of the id(1 or 2 or 3) that is being passed to edit.html using jquery or js?

Please help..

Comment: Potential duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

```
function getId() {
    var href = window.location.href,
        id = href.substr( href.indexOf('?') + 1 ).replace('id=',''); // 1, 2 , 3..
    return id;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The parameters you are passing are call the query string. See this answer on stack overflow for how to retrieve them

Code:

```
function getParameterByName(name)
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
  var results = regex.exec(window.location.search);
  if(results == null) 
    return "";
  else
    return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Credit:

[How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to get the query string with jQuery on the page edit.html?

See: [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

```
function getParameterByName(name)
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
  var results = regex.exec(window.location.search);
  if(results == null)
    return "";
  else
    return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

on edit.html: `getParameterByName('id');`

Comment: Hi, could you explain more?
So are you saying i should have a onload call on edit.html and inside the onload method call the getParameterByName('id')?

Comment: If that's what you want. Store the result of the function in a variable.